# how to select from a table containing two foriegn key

Tags: mysql

here is info table

```
u_id name email password
```

and here is course table

```
c_id title description instructor fees
```

and the cart table

```
cart_id c_id u_id
```

the c_id and u_id are forign key from info and course table
. How to write select command to display title from course and name from info using cart table

Comment: Just use two joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  c.title, i.name 
FROM 
  cart ca
  INNER JOIN course c ON ca.c_id = c.c_ID
  INNER JOIN info i ON ca.u_id = i.u_id
```